# What is the mock template for centos-7?

Tags: centos, rpm, packaging, mock

I see on [some sites they mention a centos-7 template that ships with `mock`](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-extras-x86_64/mock-1.2.17-1.el7.centos.noarch.rpm.html),

```
/etc/mock/centos-7-aarch64.cfg
/etc/mock/centos-7-armhfp.cfg
/etc/mock/centos-7-i386.cfg
/etc/mock/centos-7-ppc64.cfg
/etc/mock/centos-7-ppc64le.cfg
/etc/mock/centos-7-x86_64.cfg
```

However, on my install `mock` on `centos-7` I lack these files? Which template do I use?

From `yum info mock` I see,

### `yum info mock`

```
Installed Packages
Name        : mock
Arch        : noarch
Version     : 1.4.21
Release     : 1.el7
Size        : 741 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : epel
Summary     : Builds packages inside chroots
URL         : https://github.com/rpm-software-management/mock/
License     : GPLv2+
Description : Mock takes an SRPM and builds it in a chroot.
```

### `yumdb info mock`

```
# yumdb info mock
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
mock-1.4.21-1.el7.noarch
     checksum_data = 1e1b04f2009acef02f05aaf1af5b32a4cb5bce49eb0029803d8990f832bf09e4
     checksum_type = sha256
     command_line = install mock
     from_repo = epel
     from_repo_revision = 1574209186
     from_repo_timestamp = 1574209353
     installed_by = 1000
     origin_url = https://dfw.mirror.rackspace.com/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/m/mock-1.4.21-1.el7.noarch.rpm
     reason = user
     releasever = 7
     var_contentdir = centos
     var_cp_centos_major_version = 7
     var_infra = stock
     var_uuid = 54909cf4-080d-4942-bf31-ef058b297752
```

It seems these files aren't on the [git repo pointed to by the rpm](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/mock/tree/devel/mock-core-configs/etc/mock/templates).

Comment: I just installed `mock` from a fresh CentOS 7.7 install (`mock-1.2.17-1.el7.centos.noarch`, located in the extras repository), those files were indeed included.  Post additional information about your currently installed `mock` such as how you installed it and the output of `yum info mock`.

Comment: @GracefulRestart updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have installed a newer version of `mock` provided by EPEL.

For that package, the config files are changed from `/etc/mock/centos-7-x86_64.cfg` to `/etc/mock/epel-7-x86_64.cfg` and are provided by the RPM package `mock-core-configs`.

The newer `mock` seems to be for the transition to `dnf` and `python3`, so they may have removed architectures that they no longer wanted to maintain.  If you want the full list of configs that you referenced, you may need to downgrade to the CentOS version of `mock`.

Comment: Right. Package mock-core-configs and files /etc/mock/epel-* is the way to go. That configs is combination of CentOS + EPEL.